# Can we test if a number is a lucky number in polynomial time?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I know primality tests exist in polynomial time. But can we test if a number is a [lucky number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number) in polynomial time ?

Comment: Have you looked at the references linked in the Wikipedia article? If it's there, you win. If not, you tell us, so we don't all waste our time tracking false leads.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As far as I can tell there's very little literature on lucky numbers and none on lucky number testing.

Comment: @JSchlather, you're probably right, but I want to get OP into the habit of tracking down the links, instead of dumping the work on others.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, although it's an interesting exercise to google lucky number testing and realize these results are not what you wanted at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you're going to get a satisfactory answer to this question. I'm fairly sure the answer to your question is that there's no known polynomial time algorithm to determine if a number is lucky. The fact that Primes is in P was not shown until 2004, when people have been studying prime numbers and prime number tests for quite a long time. I certainly can't comment on whether or not there is a polynomial time algorithm for lucky numbers, probably it's in $\mathrm{NP}$ so such a question would inevitably have to answer $\mathrm{P=NP}$.

Looking at the lucky numbers they seem to have much less exploitable structure than the primes. Possibly one could develop a large theory of lucky numbers and then use this to help make progress forward. But examining the seive algorithm I highly doubt there's going to be a way to make it polynomial in terms of the input.

Comment: if testing that really is in NP, what would be the polytime checkable certificate for a lucky number? thanks a lot